Map with xinput a Stylus to two Monitors
In school we have two 86' Monitors with touch and a Controlmonitor. So i duplicate my Laptop Monitor to one 86' (via USB-C DP-2) and have an external Monitor over HDMI that is duplicated by a HDMI-Matrix to the second 86' Monitor. These have Touch.
Acutally i've a script, that maps each pointer from the two 86' Monitors correctly via its id from xinput
xrandr --output eDP-1 --primary --mode 1920x1080 --pos 0x0 --rotate normal --output HDMI-1 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 1920x0 --rotate normal --output DP-2 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 0x0 ----rotate normal --output DP-1 --off
xinput map-to-output 'Wacom HID 526B Finger touch' eDP-1
# CVTE Touch left Monitor
xinput map-to-output 11 eDP-1
# CVTE Touch right Monitor
xinput map-to-output 12 eDP-1

What i cannot use, is the Stylus from the Monitors. Because if i use the Stylus from Monitor 1, i cannot write on Monitor 2.
Is there any chance, to map the Stylus to both Monitors, like
xinput map-to-output id=?? HDMI-1 & DP-2

Thanks for your help.
